# The Morse complex of a manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

For a smooth manifold with boundary $M$ and $\partial M = V_+ \cup V_-$ two disjoint sets of boundary components, one usually defines the Morse complex of $M$ using a Morse-Smale pair $(f,X)$ such that $X$ is transverse to $\partial M$, outward pointing along $V_+$ and inward pointing along $V_-$. In particular this means that there cannot be critical points of $f$ in a small neighborhood of the boundary. The resulting homology is usually noted $H(M,V_+)$, I assume this is to suggest an isomorphism with relative singular homology but I have never seen a proof of this fact, how does one prove this statement?

Also, how would one define the "absolute" homology of $M$, meaning not relative to a subset of the components of the boundary?

Comment: What is your favourite way of showing that Morse homology is isomorphic to singular homology? In the book of Schwarz he discusses relative homology, and this falls neatly into it. You can also get this from cellular homology.

Comment: There is also a nice paper by Laudenbach explaining the cases $V_+=\emptyset$ (respectively $V_-=\emptyset$): https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5077 .